# What happened to the Imperial Fleet after the destruction of the second Death Star?

Tags: star-wars

We see in the film, that once the Death Star has blasted into oblivion, the Rebel Fleet heads for the surface of Endor. When Ackbar orders the Rebel Fleet to break off the engagement and move away from the battle, why didn't the Imperials give chase and keep attacking? Did the Imperials leave as soon as they saw the destruction or were they caught in the blast or something else?